# Transform Arrow.Table to Arrow.RecordBatch

Tags: c#, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-flight

I'm working with some Arrow data in C# as a `Table` and need to convert this to `RecordBatch` to send over the wire via Arrow Flight. It's trivial to go the other way via [`Table.TableFromRecordBatches`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/csharp/src/Apache.Arrow/Table.cs#L32) like this:

```
var schema = recordBatch.Schema;
var table = Table.TableFromRecordBatches(schema, new List<RecordBatch>{recordBatch});
```

I can't find / see a way to do the reverse. Does this exist, should it exist, is it not yet implemented?

Follow up question - should I just avoid using Table at all? It seems like most interop needs are met with `RecordBatch`, and maybe `Table` is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecordBatch` essentially is a `Table` without schema. If you observe an Apache Arrow Table, it consists of `schema` and `records` where `records` are RecordBatches.

To answer your question, yes, ideally the reverse should exist. I was facing a similar problem using Apache Arrow JS and apparently the Apache Arrow community support for JS is not that good compared to *pyarrow*,  C++ or Java.

With that being said, I think it is possible to get a RecordBatch from Table by overriding the method that returns `schema` for the table as a no-op. That's what I did to solve my problem.